# Operations that have adjoints rather than inverses

Tags: category-theory, lattice-orders, adjoint-functors

Is there a name for the operation ⊖ which is the left adjoint of natural number addition in the following way?

c ⊖ d ≤ a ≡ c ≤ a + d

Is there a name for algebraic structures like this, whose operations have adjoints rather than inverses?

Comment: Operations having adjoints rather than inverses are known as *residuated functions*. E.g., $\land, \Rightarrow, \max, \min, \gcd, \lcm, \div$ (integer division), the floor and ceiling functions, etc... are all residuated ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems an adjoint to the multiplication in a partially ordered monoid is called a *Monus*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monus.

And this kind of structure in general is called a "semiring with monus", or an *m-semiring*.

Answer (score 3):

This operation is just $\mathrm{max}(c-d,0).$ To get anything interesting happening, it's best not to be in a subcategory of a groupoid. The more general question is very broad, but for instance the theory of monoidal categories with duals covers many cases.